# Vigenere failed test :( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

Can someone help me with my code to solve this error above?I have searched for answers but they are bit different from my code.

- vigenere.c compiles.
- encrypts "a" as "a" using "a" as keyword
- encrypts "barfoo" as "caqgon" using "baz" as keyword
- encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
  **failed** expected "ciphertext: CaQ...", not "ciphertext: CaQ..."
- encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
- encrypts "world!$?" as "xoqmd!$?" using "baz" as keyword
- encrypts "hello, world!" as "iekmo, vprke!" using "baz" as keyword
- handles lack of argv[1]
  **failed** failed to execute program due to segmentation fault
- handles argc > 2
- rejects "Hax0r2" as keyword

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main(int argc,string argv[])
{
    for (int k = 0;k<strlen(argv[1]);k++)
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[1][k]))
        {}
        else
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int alpha,cipher,key,j=0,len=strlen(argv[1]);
        char a;
        string plaintext = get_string("Text: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(plaintext) ; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
                {
                    alpha = plaintext[i]-65;
                    key = argv[1][j]-65;
                    cipher = (key+alpha)%26;
                    a = (char) cipher+65;
                    printf("%c",a);
                    j=(j+1)%len;

                }
                else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                {
                    alpha = plaintext[i]-97;
                    key = argv[1][j]-97;
                    cipher = (key+alpha)%26;
                    a = (char) cipher+97;
                    printf("%c",a);
                    j=(j+1)%len;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c",plaintext[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop at the beginning accesses `argv[1]` without checking that `argc > 1` first.

Comment: You should put that loop inside the `if (argc == 2)` block.

Comment: Stop using magic numbers like `65` and `97`. Use char literals `'A'` and `'a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code handles upper and lowercase letters in the plaintext correctly, but it doesn't handle different case letters in the keyword properly. When you're processing an uppercase plaintext letter, you subtract `65` from the keyword letter, even though it might not be uppercase.

You should simply convert all keyword letters to a common case, and subtract the corresponding first letter from that to get the amount to increase by.

There's also no need to check `islower()` -- if it's not uppercase, it must be lowercase. So just use `else`.

```
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                alpha = plaintext[i]-'A';
                key = toupper(argv[1][j])-'A';
                cipher = (key+alpha)%26;
                a = (char) cipher+'A';
                printf("%c",a);
                j=(j+1)%len;

            }
            else
            {
                alpha = plaintext[i]-'a';
                key = toupper(argv[1][j])-'A';
                cipher = (key+alpha)%26;
                a = (char) cipher+'a';
                printf("%c",a);
                j=(j+1)%len;
            }
```

To fix the segmentation fault due to lack of `argv[1]`, move the loop that checks that the keyword is all alphabetic inside the `if (argc == 2)` block. You can also then use the `len` variable instead of repeating `strlen(argv[1])` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fix my code. Both the errors are fixed now and I like the way you have explained it. I really appreciate your help.